# Why is there a line through the social sharing boxes?

Tags: html, css, web, button, line

I'm currently hosting a website called "Ultradapt" - can be found at [www.ultradapt.com](http://www.ultradapt.com). And I am in the process of setting up some social sharing buttons to generate more traffic.

However, I've stumbled onto a problem regarding the social sharing buttons. If you take a look at the website above, there is a white line through the buttons. **Why is this line showing, and how do I disable it?**

Here is a quick screenshot of the problem:

[Screenshot of the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfRDv.png)

Thank you so much for your help in advance. I'm truly thankful!

Comment: Can't find the problem you're talking about. What white line and what buttons? Could you post a pic?

Comment: Welcome! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or removed at a later stage (rendering your question useless). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated the question now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Removing these lines fixed the problem: https://i.imgur.com/pSEn6yH.jpg

Comment: That's definitely a weird one. I've got no idea.

Comment: @RickSibley they did not. I've removed the lines but the problem is still ongoing.

Comment: @JakobStaudal You didn't comply to Obsidian Age's comment. Questions on Stack Overflow are required to be self-contained, meaning that it should be answerable without visiting any external links. The purpose of SO is to build a Q&A base that helps future users with the same problem. If you fix this problem, the question will become useless for future visitors.

Comment: @Ivar it is kind of hard for me to update my question including the actual code itself when I have absolutely no idea where to look. I am completely lost in the lines of codes searching for that specific spot to edit. However, I cannot find it.

Comment: Are you sure you removed it correctly: https://i.imgur.com/Qxw42lq.mp4

Comment: @JakobStaudal I understand that, but that doesn't make it on-topic here. You can take a look on how to create a [mcve]. Basically you can remove everything that is not related to the problem. If you reached that point, the code is probably small enough to fit into the question. Odds are also that by doing this, you will find the problem/solution yourself in the process.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the solution to the problem. Rick was on the right trach with the entry content. I simply wrote:

```css
.entry-content a {
 background-image: none;
}
```

And it is now running as it should.